# using wildcard in including script from node_modules

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm

I'm using npm and express.js, and would like to manage my front end dependency using npm.

I do this in my app.js

```
app.use( express.static('./') );
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/fabric/dist/'));
```

so I'm able to use  `<script src="/scripts/fabric.js"></script>` in my front end.

How do I make it dynamic to all script? like I have jquery I have to do
`app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist/'));` ?

I wish I can do this `app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/*/dist/'));`